# Why does setting shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" have no effect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm trying to turn off shadow copying in IIS to improve performance in production.

But adding that in my web.config has no effect.  Here's my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I hit the URL it takes just as long the first time, and
files still appear in 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
so it appears to have no effect.

IIS 7.5 and Windows 7. I'm testing with a tiny Hello World ASPX page.
Any ideas why this isn't working? Is this setting overridden somewhere?

Comment: What's ending up in that directory? Depending on what type of project you're using, it may still have to compile the actual `.aspx` files and put that assembly somewhere. Remember, this setting affects the assemblies in the `bin` folder - not any other assemblies that it's forced to create.

Comment: You're right, Damien. The files ending up there don't include the DLLs from the web app bin directory, but there are a number of other files there.

Comment: It is possible that the setting is being overridden in IIS Manager. Check the settings in IIS Manager and make sure that shadow copying is disabled. If it is enabled, try disabling it and then restarting the application pool.